# Delay Meteor subscribe until more resources are available

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have subscriptions users and product which give about 5000 and 7000 docs respectively. I use the data for typeahead searching in users and product forms. If we subscribe on form render, then the form takes too long to load so we subscribe on Meteor.startup, but that also makes our startup time slow.

How can we make the subscriptions run after the first screen is finished loading without touching the code for the first screen? I don't wanna do subscribe inside firstScreen.onRender() because there can be multiple first screens depending on the url entered.

I tried doing Meter.defer in Meteor.onStartup but that didn't work.

Alternatively, is there a better way to accomplish typeahead with semantic beyond loading all the data?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I strong recommend you to use the Pattern 'Template-Level Subscriptions' to make sure that you have your data ready to your templates.
Here is the link that explain this -> https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/template-level-subscriptions/

I hope that helps,

Comment: that's the problem... if i subscribe inside onCreated of the template, then the template takes too long to load. therefore i want to subscribe to it BEFORE we even get there, ideally the client isn't busy.

Comment: I understand your point. But if you implement a way to load the data before you get there you will not have a real gain in performance. The total of load time will be the same. I recommend a new approach, do you really need all these 5000, 7000 docs on your template? How about load partially? Pagination or load by scroll page. You will improve your load time, guaranteed

Comment: thanks. i see what you mean by "the total load time will be the same." even though it is the same, can it be perceived as faster if it is done when the client isn't busy? and yeah, we do need all the docs because it's a searchable dropdown as provided by semantic.